# How to use Nuget package in Azure Stream Analytics Application in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-stream-analytics

I want to use System.Data.SqlClient package in my C# function to read a value from a table in my sql database so that the same can be used in my sql Query by returning value from my UDF.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-edge-csharp-udf

But I am unable to install the package through package manager console or nuget manager. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: What VS version are you using?

Comment: - In `Visual Studio` => `Extensions`, Download the `Package Installer` and `NuGet Tools`. Now Iam able to see the enabled `Manage NuGet Packages` after reloading the Visual Studio.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNTzs.png)

Comment: Please refer [SQL Database for an Azure Stream Analytics job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/sql-reference-data)

Comment: @Harshitha , I am still unable to view this option after trying the steps you mentioned. Using Visual Studio version 17.5.4 Community Edition.